# run .exe from batch file (I'm new)

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to create a batch file to run some simulations for me automatically.

I usually use this: C:\Users\Paulo Victor\Google Drive\LCCV\Simulacoes\MODELO II\Diâmetro Variável>demoop_parallel Caso 16.ofs into cmd prompt and it works.

So, I tried to create a batch file and didn't work for me, I put:

```
start "C:\Users\Paulo Victor\Google Drive\LCCV\Simulacoes\MODELO II\Diâmetro Variável\demoop_parallel.exe" "C:\Users\Paulo Victor\Google Drive\LCCV\Simulacoes\MODELO II\Diâmetro Variável\Caso 16.ofs"
```

and it does not work, what am I doing wrong?

I know, it is a simple question, but again, I'm really new.

Comment: this is not really about programming but more windows administration. I am having troubles getting what you input where, please edit your question and make clear what exactly you see on your commandline and what exactly is the content of your batch file

Comment: done, I'm sorry. Can you understand it now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first quoted string is used as the Window Title when using the `start` command.  So use an empty set of quotes at the beginning.

```
start "" "C:\Users\Paulo Victor\Google Drive\LCCV\Simulacoes\MODELO II\Diâmetro Variável\demoop_parallel.exe" "C:\Users\Paulo Victor\Google Drive\LCCV\Simulacoes\MODELO II\Diâmetro Variável\Caso 16.ofs"
```